# why can't I put a 30% wide div next to a 70% wide div and have them both inline?

Tags: html, css

If I create a 30% wide div, inline-block next to a 70% wide div, they don't line up horizontally. I have to make them add up to less than 100%

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="w30">  
    width 30%
  </div>
  <div id="w70">  
    width 70%
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper{
  width:100%;
}
#w30{
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
}

#w70{
  background:pink;
  display:inline-block;
  width:70%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLo75s74/)

why is 30% + 70% seem to be wider than 100% ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `inline-block`, that [calculates white spaces too](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). So either have your `div` elements on the same line or use something modern such as [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

With `inline-block` (same CSS as you're using now):

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="w30">  
    width 30%
  </div><div id="w70">  
    width 70%
  </div>
</div>
```

With `flexbox` (same HTML as you're using now):

```css
#wrapper{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
#w30{
  background:yellow;
  width:30%;
}

#w70{
  background:pink;
  width:70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="w30">  
    width 30%
  </div>
  <div id="w70">  
    width 70%
  </div>
</div>
```